# Is "It would be great?" used appropriately in my sentence.

Tags: grammar

I want to send an email to a hiring manger. Is my sentence appropriate?

**It would be great If I have an opportunity to work with your Company.**

Comment: Better if you use past tense after "it would be great if". I mean say: "It would be great If I had an opportunity to work with your Company." This polite instructuer works this way.

Comment: It'll be great if you would give me an opportunity to work with your company.

Answer (score 2):

The mentioned sentence in my opinion is correct and I have used this structure in my letters lots of time, however for better understanding of conditional statements, you can search for Third Conditionals – unreal situations, 2nd conditional forms, and 1st to be familiar completely how they make sense to readers.

1. Wouldn't it be great if you knew exactly what a hiring manager would be asking you in your next interview?
2. It would be great if you can/could come to my party ...
3. It would be great if we could meet again.

   I am hopeful you can land your favorite, great job....

Good luck

Comment: Yes, I meant what you said, it happens sometimes letters dropped down. I appreciate your attention

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

> It would be great **to have** an opportunity to work with your Company.

In this way you take out the implicit conditional. After all, you are only interested in the positive result, right?